# Commutator of gamma matrices?

Tags: matrix, feyncalc

Is the matrix $\sigma_{\mu\nu}$

$$\sigma_{\mu\nu} = \frac{i}{2} [\gamma_\mu, \gamma_\nu]$$

defined in FeynRules, FeynCalc or any similar packages? I know that $\gamma_\mu$ is `Ga[mu]` in FeynRules.

Comment: PS it won't let me enclose my equation in $$ for latex...

Comment: Not sure what you did wrong; enclosing in `$$` works, as you might now see.

Comment: Funny, it said that my question contained code that wasn't formatted properly and wouldn't let me post. The preview looked fine.

Answer (score 7):

The $\gamma$ matrices are built-in, but undocumented, as `` Internal`DiracGammaMatrix[] ``. Their indexing is also a bit different from [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices):

```
Table[Internal`DiracGammaMatrix[k, "Basis" -> "Dirac"] // MatrixForm, {k, 4}]
```

$$\{\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & -i \\
 0 & 0 & i & 0 \\
 0 & i & 0 & 0 \\
 -i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}\}$$

(Other possible settings for `"Basis"` include `"Chiral"` (the default) and `"Majorana"`.)

Thus, you can implement the commutator like this:

```
Options[diracCommutator] = Options[Internal`DiracGammaMatrix];
diracCommutator[p_, q_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
   With[{pm = Internal`DiracGammaMatrix[p, opts], qm = Internal`DiracGammaMatrix[q, opts]},
        I (pm.qm - qm.pm)/2]
```

and then you can do e.g.

```
diracCommutator[2, 4, "Basis" -> "Dirac"] // MatrixForm
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & i & 0 & 0 \\
 -i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & i \\
 0 & 0 & -i & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: This is without using FeynCalc, right?

Comment: Nope, it's built-in, but *undocumented*.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $\sigma_{\mu\nu}$ is given by `Sig[mu, nu]` in FeynRules, a related package, and defined

```
Sig[mu_,nu_,ss1_,ss2_]->I/2 TensDot[Ga[mu].Ga[nu]][ss1,ss2]-I/2TensDot[Ga[nu].Ga[mu]][ss1,ss2]},\[Infinity],Heads->True];
```

in `Interfaces/FeynArtsInterface.m`.

Answer (score 1):

In FeynCalc there is `DiracSigma`

```
DiracSigma[GA[mu], GA[nu]]
```

with

```
?DiracSigma
```

> DiracSigma[a, b] stands for I/2*(a . b - b . a) in 4 dimensions. a and
>   b must have Head DiracGamma, DiracMatrix or DiracSlash. Only
>   antisymmetry is implemented.

However, you cannot have explicit Dirac indices attached to the Dirac matrices. This is something planned for the future (which is needed to use FeynCalc with QGraf)